# Build Lucene Query for multi values in one field

Tags: java, java-8, lucene

I have one field and multiple values for it and I am trying to build a simple query which should look like this

```
field:(value1 value2 value3)
```

I have a map with fields and values and I am doing something like this

```
fieldsMap 
 "field1" -> "[data1]"
 "field2" -> "[value1,value2,value3]"
```

Code to build lucene query:

```
fieldsMap
        .entrySet()
        .forEach(field -> {
            try {
                QueryParser queryParser = new ComplexPhraseQueryParser(field.getKey(), new StandardAnalyzer());
                booleanQueryBuilder.add(queryParser.parse(QueryParser.escape(field.getValue())), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Generated output:

```
+field1:data1 +(field2:val1 field2:val2 field2:val3)
```

But how can I generate something like this

```
+field1:data1 +field2:(value1 value2 value3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You already did. `+field1:data1 +(field2:val1 field2:val2 field2:val3)` is equivalent to `+field1:data1 +field2:(val1 val2 val3)`