# Lucene query does not search for word "an"

Tags: search, lucene

I've programmed a lucene search that searches for all the term an user enters in every field of an entity. This worked but now I have an issue with the word "an".

To be concrete I want to search for the words `"receptions de nouvel an"` in any order my query looks like this:

```
+description:*receptions* +description:*de* +description:*nouvel* +description:*an*
```

this gives me no results but I know that there should be 3 results.

1. Réceptions de Nouvel An MDDI/PCH
2. Réceptions de Nouvel An 2011
3. Réceptions de Nouvel An 2010

when I'm doing a query like this

```
+description:*receptions* +description:*de* +description:*nouvel*
```

I am getting the expected results. So it seems that there is a problem with the work `"an".`

Has anybody a clue for me what's wrong here and why my first query is not working?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55841110/build-lucene-query-for-multi-values-in-one-field

Comment: Thanks for the link but I don't think this has anything to do with my question. My query is right (in my opinion) and the second query works (with "an"). Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: How is the field type definition for the field `description` ? If tokenized, you should just try `+description: receptions de nouvel an`

Comment: Yes, when searching for the whole phrase you will get the expected result. But this is the searching function of my program so also "description"s that have these words in any other order (or with others words in between) should be found that's why I have to search it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default of Standart Analyzer using EnglishStopWords CharArraySet which also include "a,an,the" ex. If you want those words to  be indexed  then you migth use some custom CharArraySet or as in the blove ride off the StopWords

```
analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET);
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem was indeed that the word "an" is escaped by the english stopwords.
It seems that from version 8.0.0 on (that I don't use yet) the default constructor is switched so that it won't use the english stopwords anymore:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-7444

Comment: Yes. They are not. But if you keep using previous version of Lucene Just create your own chararrayset then it will work. But recomdattion is always last versiyon of core API's.